# Testlink has been installed, but when input index page in Chrome to login, it will redirect to install page, how could I do?

Tags: php, testing, testlink

I need to test our new software, so I installed the test manage tool TestLink on my Mac. Now I finished the install process, the automatic install program was reminded me as following pic:

[it is done, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMovf.png)

Then I've tried to open Testlink to login, input "http://localhost/testlink/index.php", but the page redirected to new installation page:

[automatically redirecting to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9nEy.png)

I read the log in /Applications/XAMPP/logs/access_log, it can not get useful information to me:

[the access_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RRuC.png)

So I can't fix it, can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot !

My environment:

- macOS Ventura 13.1 on intel i5;
- test link version 1.9.20;
- XAMPP version 8.0.25;
- php version 8.0.25;

I've tried to edit some config files like /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf and use chmod command to change /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/testlink folder's permission to 777, it also redirecting to installation page.

Comment: Contact the support of "your new software"...

Comment: Many software requires you to delete the "install" folder after you've installed the software. If you have an install folder, either delete or rename it and test.